# ¿Cómo acceder en ANDORID 9 a una USB conectada por cable OTG desde mi app en DELPHI 10.3?

Tags: android, delphi, usb, storage, delphi-rio

En un celular tengo que conectar una memoria USB que contiene un archivo de texto (hola.txt). El problema es que cuando quiero encontrar la ruta de la USB y leer el archivo esta me arroja como resultado esta cadena de texto:

> /dev/bus/usb/001/002

Pero al intentar acceder a esta ruta me arroja un error que dice que la ruta no existe, por lo que no puedo leer el archivo de texto que viene en la memoria.

Quisiera saber cómo puedo leer el archivo de texto ya que puede venir en cualquier USB.

IMPORTANTE: CABE SEÑALAR QUE ESTO NO FUNCIONÓ EN 'ANDROID 9', PERO EN VERSIONES ANTERIORES SI SE PODÍA SACAR LAS RUTAS DE TODOS LOS DISPOSITIVOS QUE TUVIERA CONECTADOS, Y ESTE CÓDIGO QUE LES DEJO ES EXCLUSIVAMENTE PARA EL CASO DE ANDROID 9, ADEMAS LA APLICACION YA CUENTA CON LOS PERMISOS "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" Y "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Les dejo la parte del código en cuestión:

```
procedure  TFrm_FileExplorer.iniciaExplorador;
const
  ACTION_USB_PERMISSION='com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION';
  var
  listItem : TListViewItem;
  nomExternal:String;
    JavaObject : JObject;
    DeviceList : JHashMap;
    Device : JUSBDevice;
    i : Jiterator;
    s : JString;
    FFilter:JIntentFilter;
    aa:TStringList;
begin
  {$IF  Defined(ANDROID)}
  // TODO ESTO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE
    aa:=TStringList.Create;
    FFilter:=TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
    if not Assigned(FFilter) then Exit;
    FFilter.addAction(TJUsbManager.JavaClass.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    JavaObject := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.USB_SERVICE);
    FUsbManager := TJUSBManager.Wrap((JavaObject as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    DeviceList := FUsbManager.getDeviceList;
    s := DeviceList.toString;
    FUsbDevice := nil;
//----------------------------------------------------------------
    i := DeviceList.values.iterator; //ESTO ME DETECTA  SI EXISTE O NO UNA USB CONECTADA

    while i.hasNext do begin //SI ENTRA A ESTE WHILE ES PORQUE LA USB ESTA CONECTADA

    Device := TJUSBDevice.Wrap((i.next as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    //EL RESULTADO DE 'Device.getDeviceName' ES '/dev/bus/usb/001/002'
    // PERO AL INTENTAR LEER MI ARCHIVO CON LA RUTA ESPECIFICA '/dev/bus/usb/001/002/carpeta_x/hola.txt'
    // ME ARROJA UN ERROR EL CUAL ME DICE QUE LA RUTA NO EXISTE
    aa.LoadFromFile(JStringtostring(Device.getDeviceName)+'/carpeta_x/hola.txt');
  end;
    {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Debes pedir dinámicamente los permisos READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y, si es necesario, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Lo comento porque no haces mención a ellos en tu post.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, lo pondré en la pregunta, ya que lo permisos ya la app ya cuenta con los permisos de lectura y escritura.

Comment: ¿Esos permisos los estás pidiendo en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Se piden al iniciar la app, por primera vez, y si no se otorgan seguirá preguntando cada vez que la app se lance.

Answer (score 1):

Con el método que estás utilizando, obtienes el *nombre del dispositivo* USB, pero no la ruta al sistema de archivos que puede estar en dicho dispositivo.

De hecho, para el sistema, el dispositivo conectado **podría no tener un sistema de archivos**, puesto que la interfaz USB es genérica. En el otro extremo, un mismo dispositivo podría tener varios sistemas de archivos, caso de un disco duro externo que puede tener varias particiones, cada una con un sistema de archivos distinto.

Dado que lo que buscas es leer y probablemente escribir un archivo, te sugiero que abandones esa ruta y te bases en el resultado del método [`getExternalFilesDirs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) del contexto de la *activity* (clase `Context`), en combinación con el método `isExternalStorageRemovable` de la clase `Environment`.

Mi traducción libre de la documentación de `getExternalFilesDirs` es:

> Retorna las rutas absolutas a los directorios específicos de la aplicación en todos los dispositivos compartidos/externos dónde la aplicación puede colocar archivos persistentes de su propiedad. Estos archivos son internos de la aplicación y típicamente no son visibles al usuario como *medios*.

He escrito este código para mostrar su uso, aunque los resultados van a variar de un dispositivo a otro y no tengo a mano un cable OTG para conectar una memoria externa (he intentado con un disco duro, pero las particiones tienen sistema de archivos NTFS, por lo que las detecta pero no las monta). Básicamente es crear un formulario con dos botones y realizar las siguientes adaptaciones:

En la clausula uses de la unidad, asegúrate de incluir las siguientes referencias:

```
uses
    Androidapi.Jni
  , Androidapi.Helpers
  , Androidapi.JNIBridge
  , Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes
  , System.IOUtils
  ;
```

Luego, declarar lo necesario de la interface `Environment`, que no viene por defecto en Delphi.

```
type
  JEnvironmentClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{D131F4D4-A6AD-43B7-B2B6-A9222BC46C74}']
    function isExternalStorageEmulated(Path: JFile): Boolean; cdecl;
    function isExternalStorageRemovable(Path: JFile): Boolean; cdecl;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/os/Environment')]
  JEnvironment = interface(JObject)
    ['{83A2E94E-7D8E-432F-BE21-AEC2115015BE}']
  end;

  TJEnvironment = class(TJavaGenericImport<JEnvironmentClass, JEnvironment>);
```

Mi código hace uso de esta función auxiliar, para mostrar el espacio disponible y total de la unidad:

```
function BytesToStr(Bytes: Int64): string;
var
  Num: Double;
  IdxPrefijo: Integer;
const
  Prefijo: array[0..7] of string = ('Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB');
begin
  Num := Bytes;
  IdxPrefijo := 0;
  while Num >= 1000 do
  begin
    Num := Num / 1024;
    Inc(IdxPrefijo);
  end;
  Result := Format('%.2f %s', [Num, Prefijo[IdxPrefijo]]);
end;
```

Finalmente, en el método asociado al OnClick del primer botón, listamos todas las unidades externas disponibles:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dirs: TJavaObjectArray<JFile>;
  ADir: JFile;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Todas las rutas de documentos externas:');
    Dirs := TAndroidHelper.Context.getExternalFilesDirs(nil);
    for I := 0 to Dirs.Length - 1 do
    begin
      ADir := Dirs.Items[I];
      Memo1.Lines.Add('  ' + JStringToString(ADir.getPath) + ' '
        + BytesToStr(ADir.getFreeSpace) + '/' + BytesToStr(ADir.getTotalSpace));
      if TJEnvironment.JavaClass.isExternalStorageRemovable(ADir) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' removable');
      if TJEnvironment.JavaClass.isExternalStorageEmulated(ADir) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' emulated');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    end;
  finally
    Memo1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Como verás, la ruta del sistema de archivos, en todos los casos, será distinta de la que estabas obteniendo antes.

Si todo pinta bien, podemos entonces definir un método para intentar obtener la ruta del sistema de archivos de la memoria externa (que va a variar entre dispositivos), por ejemplo con esta función:

```
function getOTGPath(): string;
```

Cuya implementación sería:

```
function TForm1.getOTGPath: string;
var
  Dirs: TJavaObjectArray<JFile>;
  ADir: JFile;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Dirs := TAndroidHelper.Context.getExternalFilesDirs(nil);
  for I := 0 to Dirs.Length - 1 do
  begin
    ADir := Dirs.Items[I];
    if     TJEnvironment.JavaClass.isExternalStorageRemovable(ADir)
       and not TJEnvironment.JavaClass.isExternalStorageEmulated(ADir)
    then
    begin
      Result := JStringToString(ADir.getPath);
      ForceDirectories(Result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  raise Exception.Create('No se ha detectado memoria removible');
end;
```

Finalmente, en un segundo botón, podríamos ya cargar el contenido del fichero de tu interés en el memo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(TPath.Combine(getOTGPath, 'carpeta_x/hola.txt'));
end;
```

Podemos probar guardar un archivo en esta carpeta, en el `OnClick` del segundo botón:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  FileName: string;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add('Esto es una prueba');
    FileName := TPath.Combine(getOTGPath, 'hola.txt');
    sl.SaveToFile(FileName);
    ShowMessage('Guardado en ' + FileName);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

En mi dispositivo (samsung), el resultado ha sido este:

[image: Resultado de ejecutar la aplicación]

Dado que comentas que los dispositivos de tu interés no tienen otra memoria externa, considero que el código mostrado te será funcional.

Comment: Intente esto memo1.lines.loadfromfile(JStringToString(ADir.getPath)+'/carpeta_x/hola.txt'); y me arroja el siguiente error: 'Error - No such file or directory', el resultado de la ruta de ADir.getPath fue semejante a esta '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.app1/files/DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS' y yo le concatene '/carpeta_x/hola.txt' pero mi archivo no pudo ser leido

Comment: ¿En qué dirección, relativa a la raíz de la unidad está el archivo?

Comment: @Kenneth, ¿Cuál es el resultado de la llamada a la función `getOTGPath`?

Comment: Este es el resultado de la función: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.embarcadero.Project1/files'

Comment: Project Project1.apk raised exception class EFOpenError with message 'Cannot open file "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.embarcadero.Project1/files/kenneth/hola.txt". No such file or directory'.

Comment: Lo que veo es que, aunque le pases nil a la función, devuelve una carpeta _privada_ de la app. Sospecho que la raiz de la unidad está en `/storage/emulated/0/`, por lo que tu archivo debiera estar guardado en la unidad como dentro de la carpeta  `/Android/data/com.embarcadero.Project1/files/kenneth/`. Como te comenté, no tengo por ahora los medios para probarlo, lo digo a puro cálculo, aunque estoy seguro que está documentado.

Comment: No he podido encontrar la solución a este caso espero en alguno momento me puedas ayudar, leí por algún lado que Android 9 tiene el acceso muy limitado pero no se si esto influya en lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Creo que la solución está cerca, te sugiero algo: para determinar a qué nivel de esa ruta está la raíz de la unidad, guarda un archivo, en lugar de tratar de leerlo, suponiendo que tienes un StringList llamado `sl`, algo como: `ruta := getOTGPath; ForceDirectories(Ruta); sl.SaveToFile(Ruta + '/hola.txt');`  Luego, inspecciona el contenido de la USB en una PC convencional y mira dónde ha quedado guardado el archivo.

Comment: Otra opción es que la rutina no esté devolviendo la memoria externa. Nunca me comentaste cuantas entradas produce el OnClick del botón de mi respuesta en el Memo y cómo lucen estas, también puede ser que no estemos tomando la ruta adecuada, aunque pareciera serlo.

Comment: En el Memo solo me aparece 1 ruta, no aparecen mas, pero intentare lo que dices y voy a ver en donde me guarda el archivo

Comment: Ya lo intente y lo guardo exactamente en la misma ruta 'storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.embarcadero.Project1/files/hola.txt'

Comment: En la memoria USB no guardo nada, guardo el archivo en el dispositivo.

Comment: Cuál es la configuración del dispositivo, aparte de la memoria interna, tiene una memoria externa, pero que está dentro del aparato? Estás seguro que al conectar la USB la reconoce correctamente y monta el sistema de archivos de la misma? La expectativa, como he dicho antes, es que aparezcan al menos 2 rutas al presionar el botón. La primera es la memoria externa "interna" y la segunda la USB. Por otro lado, la rutina, al no haber más de una, elevaría una excepción, no devolvería valor alguno, estás seguro que la copiaste tal cual está publicada?

Comment: El dispositivo que estoy usando no tiene memorias externas (SD Card) solo tiene la memoria interna y la memoria USB que le conecto para hacer las pruebas y esos son los resultados que obtengo, ademas lo estoy haciendo específicamente para este dispositivo ya que son los que se compraron para realizar las actividades del sistema. Te comento esto porque ya lo hice en otros dispositivos que no tienen ANDROID 9 y  antes no era tan complicado hacerlo.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, por favor leela de nuevo, espero que esto te funcione, un saludo.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, me podrías decir si lo intentaste en ANDROID 9, ya que cabe la posibilidad de que funcione en versiones anteriores pero en el 9 no!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103624/discussion-between-jachguate-and-kenneth).